# Incompatible types 'String' and 'TEdit'

Tags: delphi

this seems like a really simple one, but i'm new to delphi and google has not turned up anything...

i have an Edit field on my form and i have created a component which has a function of the form:

```
type
    TComms = class(TComponent)
  published
    function BuildPacket(const APacketData: string): string;
```

now i pass the output of the edit form to the function like so:

```
procedure TForm1.xxxxx(Sender: TObject)
var
  NewPacket: string;
begin
  NewPacket := Comms.BuildPacket(EditVal);
end;
```

and i get the error

```
Incompatible types 'String' and 'TEdit'
```

should i convert the Edit value to a string? or should my component do the conversion? i don't want to make the input a property of the component or anything - just an argument to the `BuildPacket` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, you're passing the edit box itself, and not the value of it. Try:

```
NewPacket := Comms.BuildPacket(EditVal.text);
```

Comment: It's most likely that you moved to Delphi from another language such as Visual Basic which allows such functionality (referring to a control's Text or Caption property without mentioning the property)